# regarding loading the npy file and investigating the contents inside it

Tags: python, numpy

I have been trying to output the contents of npy file, when `print(np.load('/home/ugwz/fcn/vgg16.npy', encoding='latin1'))`, part of the output looks like as follows, which is sort of hard to read.

[image]

Then I try to output the metadata of this array

```
print(np.load('/home/vgg16.npy', encoding='latin1').size)
print(np.load('/home/vgg16.npy', encoding='latin1').shape)
print(np.load('/home/vgg16.npy', encoding='latin1').ndim)
```

the output is as follows:

```
1
()
0
```

What's the best way to read and understand the `npy` file?

The additional information is as follows:

```
print(np.load('/home/vgg16.npy',encoding='latin1').dtype)

object

print(np.load('/home/vgg16.npy',encoding='latin1').item().type)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'type'


print(np.load('/home/vgg16.npy',encoding='latin1').item().shape)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: How did you create the array? My guess is that you called `np.save` with a dict of numpy arrays as the second argument.

Comment: yes, looks like the loaded npy file is a dict object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the end of your screen shot

```
....], dtype=float)]}
```

I'd expect the start to be `{akey: [array(....`.  In other words, a dictionary (one or more items), a list (of at least one item), and 1d array.

Though your size, shape, ndim values indicate that this is a single item, 0 dimensional array.  What is its `dtype`.  I'm guessing `dtype=object`.

It looks like there's a 1d array embedded in a list and/or dictionary and/or an object dtype array.

I haven't used the `encoding` parameter.  Its doc is:

> encoding : str, optional
>
> What encoding to use when reading Python 2 strings. Only useful when
>       loading Python 2 generated pickled files on Python 3, which includes
>       npy/npz files containing object arrays. Values other than 'latin1',
>       'ASCII', and 'bytes' are not allowed, as they can corrupt numerical
>       data. Default: 'ASCII'

That's consistent with this file containing a pickled object.  `pickling` is the general Python tool for saving lists, dictionaries, etc.  `np.save/load` can handle pickled objects, but save numpy arrays in its special format, in effect an array pickle.

I wonder if this file can be loaded with `pickle` (load?), and if that's any clearer?

I'd be tempted to try this load with `allow_pickle=False` just to verify whether it is trying to handle pickled objects, including `dtype=object` arrays.

Another to try is

```
 data = load...
 print(data.dtype)   # object?
 d1 = data[()]       # or
 d1 = data.item()
```

Either of those to statements should extract the single element from a 0d array.  Then try to identify `d1` (type, shape, dtype, etc).

Comment: Hi hpaulj, I have updated the original post, including the  output of  the information such as data.item().shape,  looks like it does not support those kind of information. The npy file is downloaded from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50333326/vgg16.npy

Comment: Since it is of dict object, I used keys to extract the key list.

Comment: So it's an object array that contains a dictionary.